# Combo não carrega com chamado via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando preencher um menu dropdown que, quando a torina é colocada num botão esta funciona.

Mas como quero que esse preenchimento aconteça automaticamente tão logo o documento seja carregado me vali do jQuery.ready() para isso, no entanto, a função nele invocada não funciona, ou seja, o menu não está sendo preenchido.

Código atual:

```
function PreencheCombo() {

    var str = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Cadastro/PreencheComboUf',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            str += '<label for="cbxUf" class="col-sm-4 control-label">UF</label>';
            str += '<select class="form-control col-sm-4" name="cbxUf" id="cbxUf">';
            $(data.result_combo).each(function () {
                str += '<option value=' + this.sigla + '>' + this.descricao + '</option>';
            })
            str += '</select>';

            $('#combo').html(str);
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    })
}
```

E a invocação:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    PreencheCombo();
});
```

Se eu colocar um botão para chamar a função PreencheCombo aí funciona, logo é a ready que não está funcionando.

Comment: Não esta bem claro o que estas a perguntar... dom??

Comment: Fiz uma edição e mudei para documento

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi assim:

```
window.onload = function () {
    PreencheCombo();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Que bom que tenha solucionado o problema por sua conta, mas acredito que uma explicação melhor do porquê isso acontece seja válida.

O Evento `ready` ocorre **depois** que o documento HTML é carregado ao passo que o o Evento **onload** ocorre mais tarde, depois que todo o conteúdo (como imagens) também já tenha sido.

O Evento **onload** é um Evento padrão no DOM ao passo que o Evento `ready` é específico da jQuery. O propósito do Evento `ready` é ocorrer o mais cedo possível assim que o documento é carregado, assim códigos que adicionam funcionalidade aos elementos da página não precisam esperar que todos os elementos sejam criados no DOM.

No seu caso, você invocou a função no `ready` esperando que o dropdown fosse preenchido, mas como o `ready` é disparado antes mesmo do DOM ter sido completamente preenchido, o dropdown ainda não existe para pder ser populado.